# How to sum factor variables

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I am trying on do a sum of the column "Market Capitalization" but I'm unable to because it's a dataframe and that the numbers have a B at the end.

If my dataframe is called Y what is the code necessary to calculate the sum of 533.5 + 15.449 and so on ?

[image]

Comment: First of all, are you sure that they all have a B and that none have an M or MM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum( as.numeric( sub("B$", "", as.character(Y$Capitalization) ) ) )
```

If the concern raised about possible 'MM' or 'M' entries is valid you might want to do a set of cascaded `sub` calls:

```
sum( as.numeric( sub("B$", "000000000", 
                      sub("MM", "000000",  as.character(Y$Capitalization) ) ) ) )
```

(And this would depend on what 'B', 'MM' and 'M' actually mean to the people who constructed the data.)

This is one of the more simple uses of 'regex' patterns I can think of. The pattern "B$" will match the last B in a character vector element. Because an entire vector will pass through these functions, no looping is needed. I suppose one could simply use "B", which would remove *all* the B's in "3BB", "4BBB"  in "6BxB".

Comment: @user1474184 Welcome to SO!  If this answered your question please mark it as answered by clicking the check mark next to the answer that worked for you.